# Multiple Small CRC checks or a single large CRC check?

Tags: crc, error-detection, crc16

Suppose I have L = 1024 bits to protect with CRC check using 16 extra bits. I have the choice of using either 16 CRC-1 (single parity check) or one CRC-16 check. Which option is better in terms of error detection capability?

For 16 CRC-1, our error will be declared if any CRC-1 fails. Stated in another way, to pass the CRC check, all CRC-1 checks should be passed; otherwise, an error will be declared.

Multiple CRC-1 system is implemented as follows. The 1024 bits are divided into 16 groups of 64 bits each and each 16-bit group is appended with one parity bit.

Answer (score 1):

A CRC-16 would be much better.  Your 16 CRC-1's can detect 16 errors, but only if each error happens to fall neatly in its own block.  If any of the 16 errors pair up in the same block, they will cancel each other and not be detected.

The CRC-16 on the other hand will, for example, detect 1 to 16 one-bit errors that occur in a burst within 16 bits.

Comment: CRC-16 can detect a single burst up to 16 bits long. Some 4 or more error bit patterns will fail to be detected. 3 or any odd number of bits in error can be detected if the CRC-16 is composed of two factors, one of them being (x+1) which acts as a parity check. For example, a CRC using hex 0x11021 has "prime" factors 0xF01F and 0x3 (with the 0x3 acting as a parity check).